# use pandas to make pivot_table but an error occur

Tags: python, pandas

I have the head of a dataframe like this and I want to make a pivot_table.

```
    user_id     item_id cate_id action_type action_date
0   11482147    492681  1_11    view          15
1   12070750    457406  1_14    deep_view     15
2   12431632    527476  1_1     view          15
3   13397746    531771  1_6     deep_view     15
4   13794253    510089  1_27    deep_view     15
```

There are 20000+ user_id,and 37 cate_id, 5 action_type.
I want to make a pivot_table like this which I do it with excel.The values in the table should be the value_count for every user_id with every cate_id.
[pivot_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk9so.png)
I've try the following code.

```
user_cate_table = pd.pivot_table(user_cate_table2,index = ['user_id','cate_id'],columns=np.unique(train['action_type']),values='action_type',aggfunc=np.count_nonzero,fill_value=0)
```

And I got this message.

```
ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length
```

the head of dataframe user_cate_table2.

```
    user_id     item_id cate_id action_type
0   11482147    492681  1_11    1.0
1   12070750    457406  1_14    2.0
2   12431632    527476  1_1     1.0
3   13397746    531771  1_6     2.0
4   13794253    510089  1_27    2.0
5   14378544    535335  1_6     2.0
6   1705634     535202  1_10    1.0
7   6943823     478183  1_3     2.0
8   5902475     524378  1_6     1.0
```

Comment: What means `np.unique(train['action_type'])` ? Unique values of column with another dataframe?

Comment: yes,the original dataframe named train.That's what I showed at the top

Comment: So there are 2 dataframes and need `pivot_table` with them? Can you add sample of second dataframe with desired output? Thank you.

Comment: OK.actually the dataframe user_cate_table2 is transformed from the dataframe train.I just change the different action_type to different number.

Comment: So you add desired output?

Comment: I've post a pic in the question. Plz click the word 'pivot_table'. I don't know how to show it in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(['user_id','cate_id', 'action_type']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
action_type       deep_view  view
user_id  cate_id                 
11482147 1_11             0     1
12070750 1_14             1     0
12431632 1_1              0     1
13397746 1_6              1     0
13794253 1_27             1     0
```

Another solution with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['user_id','cate_id'], 
                     columns='action_type', 
                     values='item_id', 
                     aggfunc=len, 
                     fill_value=0)
print (df1)
action_type       deep_view  view
user_id  cate_id                 
11482147 1_11             0     1
12070750 1_14             1     0
12431632 1_1              0     1
13397746 1_6              1     0
13794253 1_27             1     0
```

Comment: yet again I arrive at the same answer as @jezrael, who posted while I compiled mine

Comment: @MaartenFabré - Thank you. I check your answer and  it is a bit different, but I have no idea if OP want something like my solution or your.

Comment: I think `.size` uses `.np.count_nonzero`, so that comes down to the same, and I didn't use the `fill_value`. The rest is comparable

Comment: @Chunk_Ning - Thank you for patience ;)

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use `pivot_table`. You can use `groupby` and `unstack`

```
df.groupby(['user_id', 'cate_id', 'action_type'])['action_date'].agg(np.count_nonzero).unstack('action_type')
```

`pivot_table` works too but not you misunderstood the `columns=` parameter

```
pd.pivot_table(df,index = ['user_id','cate_id'],columns=['action_type'],aggfunc=np.count_nonzero,fill_value=0)
```